# IIS Application Pool logon credentials stops .net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, .net-core, iis-8, asp.net-core-3.1

I have a dedicated service account I am using to run my application pool's identity with on IIS8. However the application pool immediately fails with a WAS logon error.

I am using the latest .net core 3.1 MVC application simply the basic weatherforcaster example:

```
Log Name:      System
Source:        Microsoft-Windows-WAS
Date:          13/03/2020 11:42:27
Event ID:      5021
Task Category: None
Level:         Warning
Keywords:      Classic
User:          N/A
Computer:      **********************
Description:
The description for Event ID 5021 from source Microsoft-Windows-WAS cannot be found. Either the component that raises this event is not installed on your local computer or the installation is corrupted. You can install or repair the component on the local computer.
```

I wish I could be more descriptive but we gave the dedicated user "Service account" permissions and it worked briefly then abruptly stopped. Infrastructure have provided the maximum level of permissions, however, still getting the error.

SDK module version is 3.1.2

**Update**

Managed to prove this is not .net related, I uploaded a static html file and still IIS was erroring.

kind regards,

Comment: Is this relevant to your issue? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21637547/error-5021-creating-a-managed-service-account

Comment: Thank you it sounds similar though that's orientated to .net 4 framework. I shall give it a go now to see if it makes any differences though

Comment: Sadly none of the options worked, worth noting that MSA accounts are slight different to the ones we're using

Comment: In Windows Event Viewer, click the log entry and see the XML view on its Details tab. That should give you the raw data on what's wrong. Only from there you can move on without guessing.

Comment: Had a look at the XML results and no more information other than provided above. However, going off you comment I managed to prove that this isn't .net related as I add a static html file into IIS and recieved the same error

Comment: In my opinion, you don't provide the right error log, without right error log we couldn't find out the reason and solution. I suggest you could also check the IIS log to tell us the details error status and enable the fail request tracing to find out which module throw the error and the details error message. Details about how to use FRT in IIS, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/troubleshoot/using-failed-request-tracing/troubleshooting-failed-requests-using-tracing-in-iis).

Comment: Thanks Brando, very useful article I will implement and get back asap with the results

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the below article:
https://social.technet.microsoft.com/wiki/contents/articles/51723.sp2016-application-pool-issue.aspx

Turns out I needed to add batch logon permissions to the IIS_IUSRS and the service account needs to have logon on as a service permission as well.

Articles advice to resolve:

> Ah, checking on Local security policy, Local Policy and user assignment you’ll find a policy for “Log on as a batch job”, the identity of your application accounts need to be listed as below. It’ll be helpful after policy updates to re-enter identity of app pool and do IISReset.